# Java android right icons menu

Tags: java, android

I want to create a right icons menu . Can I do it whis menu NavigationView ?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can but you have to create your own custom layout with animation.

Comment: yes , make layout background transparent

Comment: Take a look at this [library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is layout example for your screenshot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/white_magazine" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/white_magazine" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/white_magazine" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/white_magazine" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/white_magazine" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not implement that as `NavigationView` but rather use combination of `FrameLayout` to display the menu on the right side.